# Multiply 2x2 Matrix in Python Recursively? No nested loops or numpy

Tags: python, recursion, matrix, multiplication

I'm having a difficult time finding a very simple program that multiplies two 2x2 matrices recursively. Can anyone help me out? Just need to multiply `X` and `Y` without `numpy` or using nested loops.

```
X = [[1, 2],
     [2, 3]]

Y = [[2, 3],
     [3, 4]]
```

FWIW - Here's my naïve method :)

```
X = [[1, 2],  
    [2, 3]]


Y = [[2, 3],  
     [3, 4]]

result = [[0, 0],  
          [0, 0]]

for i in range(len(X)):
    for j in range(len(Y[0])):
        for k in range(len(Y)):
            result[i][j] += X[i][k] * Y[k][j]

for r in result:
    print(r)  

# ANS = [8, 11], [13, 18]
```

_________________________ Per comments below - Recursive Strassen's

```
import numpy as np
def split(matrix):
    row, col = matrix.shape
    row2, col2 = row // 2, col // 2
    return matrix[:row2, :col2], matrix[:row2, col2:], matrix[row2:, :col2], matrix[row2:, col2:]


def strassen_recur(x, y):
    if len(x) == 1:
        return x * y

    a, b, c, d = split(x)
    e, f, g, h = split(y)

    p1 = strassen_recur(a, f - h)
    p2 = strassen_recur(a + b, h)
    p3 = strassen_recur(c + d, e)
    p4 = strassen_recur(d, g - e)
    p5 = strassen_recur(a + d, e + h)
    p6 = strassen_recur(b - d, g + h)
    p7 = strassen_recur(a - c, e + f)

    c1 = (p5 + p4 - p2 + p6)
    c2 = (p1 + p2)
    c3 = (p3 + p4)
    c4 = (p1 + p5 - p3 - p7)

    c = np.vstack((np.hstack((c1, c2)), np.hstack((c3, c4))))

    return c

print(strassen_recur(x, y))
```

I also have a naive Strassen method written as well. But like I mentioned, I was just hoping somebody had something quick to show me so I didn't have to spend a lot of time trying to figure it out. It's all good.

Comment: Hi Joy. Obviously, this is some sort of exercise. Please take a moment to read [these guidelines](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334823/5014455). Please help us understand your background, what research you may have done, and what attempts you've made. Try to ask us something specific about your own implementation

Comment: Yes, this is a personal challenge to myself that I can't wrap my head around. I have a program written that implements the iterative method (with the three traditional nested loops) and produces an output into a "result" matrix of zeroes. I've looked at a lot of pseudocode for the recursive method, but I'm unable to understand it in simple terms. The Geeks to Geeks recursive formula is super intense. I'm just looking for something very very simple so I can understand the logic behind it.

Comment: Note that python has a cool syntax using generator expressions and builtin functions that allow you to write the innermost loop as `result[i][j] = sum(X[i][k] * Y[k][j] for k in range(len(X)))`.

Comment: Could you please clarify what it is that you call "the recursive method"? There exist more than one method to calculate the product of two matrices

Comment: @Stef - thank you for the tip on the generator expression! As for the methods of calculating the product on matrices- so far, I'm only seeing two: iteratively (the program posted) or recursively. If there's any other method/algorithm, I'd love to see it! I have a recursive Strassen's program I can currently run (the code is long), that I'll post below- however, the point of OP was to see if anyone had a short snippet I could "borrow". Kinda like a copy and paste job :) I'll probably just end up tinkering with the Strassen algorithm until I get it. Oh well.

Comment: @Stef - looks like the recursive Strassen's is too long for a comment. I'll edit the OP.

Comment: @JoyBrock It's just that "iterative" and "recursive" is really really vague and hardly describes an algorithm. If you have a program with a for-loop, it's very easy to emulate it with a recursive function. But that's really the same algorithm.

Comment: @Stef - That's interesting to me that the difference between iteration and recursion is vague! I say that very genially :) But, I'm not so sure that emulating a recursive function from a for loop is "very easy"- at least it isn't to me, haha! Like I said, I'll figure it out. Was just hoping someone could "throw me a bone" and save me the time. Thank you for taking the time to comment, I appreciate it :)

Comment: @Stef - Oh! One last thing, I forgot to mention that this is allll within the "divide and conquer" paradigm that I'm referencing, as that's the algorithm I'm trying to get a handle on :)

Comment: For instance: `def calculate_cell(i, j, k=0, acc=0): if k = len(X): return acc; else: return calculate_cell(i, j, k+1, acc + X[i][k] * Y[k][j])` then you write `result[i][j] = calculate_cell(i, j)` and there you have replaced your `for`-loop with a recursive function.

Comment: @Stef - thank you so much. I really appreciate it! I'm going to copy it out and look at it in my IDE and find out why my brain just isn't processing this :/ Again, thank you- thank you! All the cookies to you~ Have a great day!

Comment: @JoyBrock But note that the code I just wrote is definitely not a divide-and-conquer algorithm. It just iterates through the values of `k` to calculate the sum, but with a recursive function instead of a `for`-loop.

Comment: @Stef - yes, for sure. Just wanted to give a little insight to where I was heading. Just wanted a little program for calculating the product of two 2x2 matrices recursively for my own personal "thingy" :D

Comment: "two 2x2 matrices" are neither interesting nor insightful, and I think such a special case actually makes it *harder* to write recursive code for it. With pretty much nothing to divide and conquer, it's hard to think of dividing and conquering at all. Better multiply an m×n matrix with an n×p matrix. Will also be better for testing.

Comment: Or maybe start by multiplying two n×n matrices, where n is a power of 2. Then you actually have something to meaningfully divide and conquer, but without the hassle of special cases that distract from the core algorithm. Once you have that, you can then adjust it to handle other sizes.

Comment: @KellyBundy - You said, "two 2x2 matrices" are neither interesting nor insightful, and I think such a special case actually makes it harder to write recursive code for it." Ok, good-- so I'm TOO crazy, haha! This was just a "personal" thing that I was looking for help on. Maybe it will never help anyone else, but that's ok- Stef in the comments came to the rescue, and it solved my problem. Cheers! <3

Comment: It's of course up to you, but I doubt even Stef would consider the question answered. As they said, their solution isn't divide-and-conquer. My point is that you (and others) would benefit from changing the question to multiplying larger matrices (either arbitrary sizes or quadratic powers-of-2). You'd learn much more from that. (Although that might be a duplicate question then, feels likely that that has been asked before.)

Comment: @KellyBundy - I'm confused. If *I* asked the question and Stef answered it sufficiently *for me* as the asker of the question, then... what does it matter? Not trying to be rude, but the point of the question was simplicity. Get me a very small 2x2 matrix multiply it by another 2x2 recursively, if anyone could. Shoot, I know 3x5 can be done recursively. I just was hoping for a simple answer to a simple question. Why make it harder? Again, I don't mean any disrespect as I'm trying to be friendly- but dang :::scratching head:::

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the answer in the event anyone is ever looking for a recursive solution to multiplying two matrices that are 2x2... or 3x3, 4x4 whatever. You would just have to change your number of rows/columns and add additional for-loops. It's not the prettiest, but it works. Maybe someone out there can make it even better?

```
X = [[1, 2],
     [2, 3]]

Y = [[2, 3],
     [3, 4]]

result = [[0, 0],
          [0, 0]]
i = 0
j = 0
k = 0

def multiplyMatrixRec(row1, col1, X, row2, col2, Y, result):

    if j < col2:
        if k < col1:
            result[i][j] += X[i][k] * Y[k][j]
            k += 1
            multiplyMatrixRec(row1, col1, X, row2, col2, Y, result)
        j += 1
        multiplyMatrixRec(row1, col1, X, row2, col2, Y, result)
    i += 1
    multiplyMatrixRec(row1, col1, X, row2, col2, Y, result)


def multiplyMatrix(row1, col1, X, row2, col2, Y):
    for i in range(row1):
        for j in range(col2):
            print(result[i][j], end=" ")
        print()

row1 = 2
col1 = 2
row2 = 2
col2 = 2
multiplyMatrix(row1, col1, X, row2, col2, Y)
```

Output:

8  11
13 18

Cheers!